# Django: Create objects from list of inequal dicts

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to call MODEL.objects.create() and map values from a list of dicts with inequal keys?
Usually, I would write some IF statements but that might result in a lot of most the same code.

Example code:

```
accounts = [
    {'name': 'A', 'age': 18, 'food': 'pizza'},
    {'name': 'B', 'age': 20, 'shoe': 'adidas'},
]

for a in accounts:
    Account.objects.create(
        name=a['name'],
        age=a['age'],
        food=a['food'], # SET ONLY IF IN DICT OTHERWISE TAKE DEFAULT 
        shoe=a['shoe']  # SET ONLY IF IN DICT OTHERWISE TAKE DEFAULT
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Prefixing a dict-like argument with `**` unpacks it into keyword arguments, this will only pass the fields/keys that exist in the dict. If you don't pass a field to `create` the default will be used if defined

```
accounts = [
    {'name': 'A', 'age': 18, 'food': 'pizza'},
    {'name': 'B', 'age': 20, 'shoe': 'adidas'},
]

for a in accounts:
    Account.objects.create(**a)
```